# Event handler performance issue in Angular 4 / 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Sorry if my question is silly, but we are facing a latency issue in our application.
KEYPRESS event handler is the culprit. We are using this below directive in the entire application. It checks `KeyPress` through `HostListener`. When key pressed, this directive checks the value with regexp and does `preventDefault` if condition is false.

```
private regexMap = { // add your own
    '999': /^([0-9]){0,3}$/g,
    '9999': /^([0-9]){0,4}$/g,
    ...
    ...
}

@HostListener('keypress', [ '$event' ])
public nInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
        return;
    }
    this.pattern = this.regexMap[this.validationFormat];
    const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.pattern)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue. Will `debounceTime` fix this issue? I am not sure how to add debounce to this method. Please someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Where is the performance problem?

Comment: I have faced the same issue, Streaming validation is bad for web based application in general. It is better to use on focus out, rather than keypress or keydown or keyup, that way code runs once user is done typing.

Comment: when i press some value in textbox, autocomplete where ever i bind this directive. I m getting latcny when i press some value (it take 10 sec for each value) can't access any value or field on app it hand for 10 second. If i type BLR then it take 30+s @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: FIXED issue with DebounceTIme :) Posted Answer below. Thanks for you helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed issue with DebounceTime :) just added debounce time with help Subject.
Basically when user enter something it stop all action, then send EVENT(key pressed value) to SUBJECT and In subject debounce Time wait 300ms and then do function test

```
    private keyPressed = new Subject();
    private subscription: Subscription;
    private pattern: RegExp;
    private regexMap = { // add your own
     '999': /^([0-9]){0,3}$/g,
     '9999': /^([0-9]){0,4}$/g,
      ...
      ...
   }
    private specialKeys: string[] = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home'];

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.keyPressed.pipe(debounceTime(300)).subscribe(
            (event) => this.checkRegExpression(event)
        );
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) public nInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.keyPressed.next(event);
    }

    private checkRegExpression(event) {
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        this.pattern = this.regexMap[this.validationFormat];
        const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
        if (next && !String(next).match(this.pattern)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming that you want to keep using keypress events, which fires for every keypress by user

**Try optimizing the Regex:**

i.e remove `g` and brackets from regex. Make the regex like this -

```
/^[0-9]{0,3}$/
```

For more tricks refer:  [Regex Optimizations](https://www.loggly.com/blog/five-invaluable-techniques-to-improve-regex-performance/)

> Websites are particularly bad with Streaming Validation (i.e. Validating text, live!)

1. If it is okay to not have a streaming validation check, then use focus lost event, i.e. run your code after focus is lost from text field.
2. Or better yet, do it like Angular documentation suggests [Email Validation Demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vkgmbaepodbg?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts), don't correct the mistakes, just point it out, user will correct it.